# can Tomcat forceful shutdown be caught through catch block with type Exception

Tags: java, tomcat

Can Tomcat forceful shutdown be caught through catch block with type Exception ?
If this is not possible, what are the ways to handle unexpected shutdown for Tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Have a look at the kill statements in `bin/catalina.sh`: `kill -9 $PID` in case of forcing shutdown.

What do you want to do?

There are quite some software packages which observe running processes and can do actions, e.g. restart the killed process. You could simply create a little shell script which periodically checks if tomcat is running and, in case this is not true, do some alternative action.